# .pyファイルをpyinstallerでexe化して実行した所、エラー表示

Tags: python3, pyinstaller

.pyファイルをpyinstallerでexe化して実行した所、エラー表示。

```
(base) C:\Users\genki>C:\Users\genki\Downloads\dist\test01.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test01.py", line 7, in <module>
NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined
[9180] Failed to execute script test01
```

上記エラー文を翻訳

"トレースバック（最後の最後の呼び出し）：
のファイル "test01.py"、7行目
NameError：名前 'get_ipython'が定義されていません
[9180]スクリプトtest01の実行に失敗しました
"
"NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined"を検索参照して解決を試みましたが、
混沌を深め…本サイトへの投稿となりました。
ご教授お願いします。

下記に".pyファイル"添付します。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                               
# coding: utf-8                             
                                
# In[1]:                                
                                
                                
get_ipython().system('pip3 install -U selenium')                                
                                
                                
# In[2]:                                
                                
                                
get_ipython().system('pip3 install webdriver_manager')                              
                                
                                
# In[3]:                                
                                
                                
from selenium import webdriver                              
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager                                
                                
                                
# In[4]:                                
                                
                                
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())                              
driver.get('https://scraping-for-beginner.herokuapp.com/login_page')                                
                                
                                
# In[5]:                                
                                
                                
elem_username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')                               
elem_username.send_keys('imanishi')                             
                                
                                
# In[ ]:
```

・コメントアウト実行しました。（意味も理解）
・"pyファイル内にfrom IPython import get_ipythonとかいて python で動かす"
　とありますが、下記の場所でいいのでしょうか？

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from IPython import get_ipython
```

又、”変換していない.pyファイルをPythonまたはIPythonで実行させてみる”とは、
下記の方法でいいのでしょか？

```
(practice) C:\Users\genki\Downloads>python                      
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  9 2021, 11:43:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32                        
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                      
>>> test04.py
```

```
(practice) C:\Users\genki\Downloads>IPython                             
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  9 2021, 11:43:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]                               
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information                               
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.                                
                                
In [1]: test04.py
```

Answer (score 0):

それら2つの`get_ipython().system(...)`の行は不要でしょう。
.pyに変換する前かPyInstallerで処理する前に、コメントアウトするか削除しておいてください。

その関数はJupyterLabで`!pip3 install ...`した内容が変換されただけであり、それはJupyterLabの環境で1度だけ実行されればJupyterLabの中でも不要になるはずの行です。

こちらの記事を参考に。
[JupyterLabで.pyデータを書き出したら「NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined」が出た](http://ziyuudesu.seesaa.net/article/475557783.html)
以下は抜粋です。

> JupyterLabでコーディングをしたあと、問題なく動いたので「.py」ファイルに書き出しをしたら、、、
>
> どうやら7行目に問題があるみたいなので見てみると
>
> あれ？JupyterLabでは↓↓だったはず！
>
> !pip install selenium
>
> JupyterLabで「!pip install 〇〇」の部分をコメントアウトして「.py」に書き出して実行した所...動きました⤴⤴

該当の行が`!pip3 install ...`ではなく、毎回の動作に必要な行の場合はこちらでしょう。
[JupyterLabからエクスポートしたファイルをローカルで動かしたい](https://teratail.com/questions/268980)

> `NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined` とエラーが出ているので、`get_ipython` が定義されていません。
>
> > コマンドプロンプト上で　python　と打って、pyファイルをドラッグしたのですが
>
> とありますが、解決方法は以下の2通りあると思います。
>
> - `python` ではなくて `ipython` とする
> - pyファイル内に `from IPython import get_ipython` とかいて `python` で動かす

あるいは置き換えるなら上記よりも`os`モジュールの[os.system(command)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/os.html#os.system)か`subprocess`モジュールの[subprocess.run(...)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)の方が良さそうですが。

---

追記内容対応：

現在記述されている`get_ipython().system(...)`の行は不要なので、`from IPython import get_ipython`を追加する必要はありません。
ただしもし本当に必要ならその呼び出す行よりも前にimportしておく必要があります。

”変換していない.pyファイルをPythonまたはIPythonで実行させてみる”とは、スクリプトファイル名の文字列を入力するのではなく、ファイルの中身をコピペするか、`python test04.py`のようにpython起動時のパラメータにスクリプトファイル名(カレントフォルダでなければフルパス)を指定するものです。

Comment: ご助言、ありがとうございます。７行目＃実行してみましたが、同じエラー表示。pyファイル内にfrom IPython import get_ipython とかいてexe作成実行しましたが同じ表示でダメでした。

Comment: エラーの発生した行は変化したのではないですか？ 変化が無ければ編集結果をセーブしていないか、編集結果をPyInstallerに渡していないのでしょう。あるいは以前に作成したものが消去されずにいてそれが動作しているとか。例えば編集しただけでPyInstallerで変換していない.pyファイルをPythonまたはIPythonで実行させてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ・コメントアウト実行しました。（意味も理解）
・"pyファイル内にfrom IPython import get_ipythonとかいて python で動かす"
　とありますが、下記の場所でいいのでしょうか？

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from IPython import get_ipython

```

Comment: 又、”変換していない.pyファイルをPythonまたはIPythonで実行させてみる”とは、
下記の方法でいいのでしょか？

```
(practice) C:\Users\genki\Downloads>python      
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  9 2021, 11:43:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32      
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.      
>>> test04.py      
```

```

Comment: ```
(practice) C:\Users\genki\Downloads>IPython        
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  9 2021, 11:43:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]        
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information        
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.        
        
In [1]: test04.py　　＊すみません。長くなったので三つに分けて送りました。

Comment: コメントに書かれても書式などが反映されないので質問の方に変更内容や実験結果を追記(元の質問内容は変えずに)してみてください。