# pyinstaller myprogram.py --onefile --debug allのエラーについて

Tags: python, python3, pyinstaller

環境：
Windows 10
Anaconda 3

pythonのファイルをPyInstallerでexe化しましたが、エラーが出ました。

```
 (practice) C:\Users\genki\Downloads>C:\Users\genki\Downloads\dist\test05.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):              
  File "test05.py", line 13, in <module>                
    get_ipython().system('pip3 install webdriver_manager')              
NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined                
[14540] Failed to execute script test05
```

以下のサイトを参考にして調査しました。

[PyInstallerで作成した実行可能ファイル(.exe)が動かないときの調査方法](https://qiita.com/q_masa/items/93872744f63ed97a54d8)

```
(practice) C:\Users\genki\Downloads>pyinstaller myprogram.py --onefile --debug all                      
109 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6                      
109 INFO: Python: 3.9.7 (conda)                     
140 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0                       
140 INFO: wrote C:\Users\genki\Downloads\myprogram.spec                     
140 INFO: UPX is not available.                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                      
  File "C:\Users\genki\anaconda3\envs\practice\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 10, in <module>                     
    sys.exit(run())                     
  File "C:\Users\genki\anaconda3\envs\practice\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run                     
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))                      
  File "C:\Users\genki\anaconda3\envs\practice\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build                        
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)                       
  File "C:\Users\genki\anaconda3\envs\practice\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main                     
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))                      
  File "C:\Users\genki\anaconda3\envs\practice\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build                        
    exec(code, spec_namespace)                      
  File "C:\Users\genki\Downloads\myprogram.spec", line 6, in <module>                       
    a = Analysis(['myprogram.py'],                      
  File "C:\Users\genki\anaconda3\envs\practice\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 191, in __init__                     
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)                      
ValueError: script 'C:\Users\genki\Downloads\myprogram.py' not found
```

以下のエラー文を検索して解決の手がかりを得ようとしましたが…。

```
raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script) ValueError: script 'C:\Users\genki\Downloads\myprogram.py' not foundとの一致はありません。
```

ご教授、宜しくお願いします。

.pyファイル

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


#!pip3 install -U selenium


# In[1]:


get_ipython().system('pip3 install webdriver_manager')


# In[2]:


from selenium import webdriver                  
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


# In[3]:


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())                      
driver.get('https://scraping-for-beginner.herokuapp.com/login_page')


# In[4]:


elem_username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')                   
elem_username.send_keys('imanishi')


# In[1]:





# In[ ]:
```

～追記
▲下記に自身の工程を記します。

1,「アナコンダプロンプト」起動。
2.(base) C:\Users\genki>conda activate practice
3,(practice) C:\Users\genki>conda install pyinstaller
4,(practice) C:\Users\genki>cd C:\Users\genki\Downloads
5,(practice) C:\Users\genki\Downloads>pyinstaller test05.py

…distフォルダの中にtest05名のフォルダ作成される。
…test05名のフォルダの中にtest05.exeファイルあり。
…test05.exeファイルをWクリックすると、パッと消える。
…test05.exeファイルを、「アナコンダプロンプト」で実行。（下記）

(practice) C:\Users\genki\Downloads>C:\Users\genki\Downloads\dist\test05\test05.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test05.py", line 19, in 
from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
[2252] Failed to execute script test05

…上記エラーは、二つのコメントアウトの時と同じエラー

▲"それからちなみ…確認してみましたか？"についての自身の工程

…ジュピターラボから.pyに変換した。
…test05.pyをｗクリック。
…VsCode起動。
…ターミナル実行。
…下記に記す。（長いので中間割愛）

PS C:\Users\genki> conda activate base
conda : 用語 'conda' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。名前が正しく記述されていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1

- conda activate base
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

割愛

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_93.0.4577 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

Comment: エラーメッセージによれば `C:\Users\genki\Downloads\myprogram.py` というファイルがない、とのことですが、実際には `C:\Users\genki\Downloads\test05.py` がデバッグ対象ではないのですか？

Comment: C:\Users\genki\Downloads\test05.py がデバッグ対象ではないのですか？…の意味が分かりません。

Comment: 実行するのは `pyinstaller test05.py --onefile --debug all` ではないのか？、という意味です。

Comment: すみません。その通りです。

Answer (score 0):

前回のQ&A [.pyファイルをpyinstallerでexe化して実行した所、エラー表示](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/82618/26370) の回答冒頭に書いた通り、`test05.py`の`get_ipython().system('pip3 install webdriver_manager')`または.pyに変換する前の`!pip3 install webdriver_manager`もコメントアウトしてください。

> それら2つの`get_ipython().system(...)`の行は不要でしょう。
> .pyに変換する前かPyInstallerで処理する前に、コメントアウトするか削除しておいてください。
>
> その関数はJupyterLabで`!pip3 install ...`した内容が変換されただけであり、それはJupyterLabの環境で1度だけ実行されればJupyterLabの中でも不要になるはずの行です。

`!pip3 install -U selenium`しかコメントアウトしていないために発生しているエラーです。

---

質問タイトルの`pyinstaller myprogram.py --onefile --debug allのエラーについて`というのは[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)であり、最初に発生している`NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined [14540] Failed to execute script test05`とは何の関係も無いことなので忘れてもらってかまいません。

Comment: test05.pyにて#!pip3 install -U selenium
#!pip3 install webdriver_managerの二つをPlnstaller実行前に処理してpyinstaller myprogram.py --onefile --debug allを実行しましたが、ダメでした。```Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "test05.py", line 19, in <module>     
    from selenium import webdriver     
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'     
[4792] Failed to execute script test05```

Comment: PyInstallerの処理対象に指定した`myprogram.py`とエラーメッセージに表示されているスクリプト名`File "test05.py"`や`Failed to execute script test05`が合っていませんので、何か違う物を実行していると思われます。そしてエラーメッセージでは`No module named 'selenium'`となっているので、test05の方は`--onefile`を指定せずにPyInstallerで処理して、distフォルダーの`test05`以外のファイルやフォルダーの何かをコピーし忘れているとか、モジュールパスに登録されていない等の可能性が考えられます。それからちなみにPyInstallerで処理する前の`test05.py`を`python test05.py`のようにpythonインタプリタのスクリプトとして実行した場合は正常に起動・終了するのを確認してみましたか？

Comment: ご助言、ありがとうございます。質問にコメントの追加を書きました。

Comment: フォルダbuildの中にmyprogramのフォルダがあり、中は空です。又、このフォルダは今日の作成でなく、９月２４日の更新で…多分pyinstaller myprogram.py --onefile --debug all実行時に作成されたと思います。

Comment: フォルダツリーの構成・作り方のセンスみたいなものが養われていない様子や、何か操作を行ってエラーが発生したのに原因を突き止めたり対処していないように見えるので、もっと一貫した記事通りに進めていれば理解が進むようなコース的な教材を探して学習することをお勧めします。あるいはそういう記事の部分は済んでいて少し違うことに手を出そうとしているのかもしれませんが、そのための環境構築や作業手順についての理解があるようには見えません。それでも手っ取り早くやりたいなら、例えば一旦JupyterLabで作ったソースは忘れてこんな記事を参考に作業してみては？ [Python SeleniumでChromeを操作exe化までの基本操作サンプルソース付](https://www.studio-chips.com/python-selenium-chrome-exe/)

Comment: ご指摘を真摯に受け止め、自身のスタイルを一考してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。